# How to simplify and make efficient my condition?

Tags: shell, sed, ansible

I have a shell script which check if my yml file start with some specific comment.
test.yml

```
#Version : 1.2
#OS : ubuntu
#Author : JJ
#ect : ect
```

Shell script:

```
FILE=test.yml   

if [[ ! $(sed '1!d' $FILE) =~ ^#Version: ]] ; then
    echo "1. line bad"
fi

if [[ ! $(sed '2!d' $FILE) =~ ^#Version: ]] ; then
    echo "2. line bad"
fi 
if idem
fi
if idem
fi
if idem
fi
```

Is there a way to simplify that ? I tried to combine that in one line but not working.
Is there a way to put several files to check and to have the input for the specific files ?
When I tried the test on  several files I don't see which one is impacted.

Comment: You might want to consider posting your request at the sister site, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where you'll get recommendations on optimization and structure on already working code.

Comment: You might want to revert the questin, this is now not readable at all

Comment: What is the expected result? 1) Variable e.g. {dict: {test1.yml: ok}, {test2.yml: ko}, ...} 2) Replace headers of all files 3) Anything else?

Answer (score 2):

1. Invoking a new command for each line will be slow.
2. Opening and closing the file for each line will be slow.

Just use bash... open the file once and read the lines.

```
exec 3<"$file"
if ! IFS= read -r -u 3 line && [[ ! $line =~ ^#Version: ]]; then : ...; fi
if ! IFS= read -r -u 3 line && [[ ! $line =~ ^#OS: ]]; then : ...; fi
if ! IFS= read -r -u 3 line && [[ ! $line =~ ^#Author: ]]; then : ...; fi
: ...
exec 3<&-
```

> Is there a way to simplify that ?

Then generic version is easy anyway - store regexes in an array:

```
linesrgx=(
    "^#Version:"
    "^#OS:"
)
for ((i=0;i<${#linesrgx[@]};++i)); do
     if ! IFS= read -r -u 3 line &&
          [[ ! $line =~ ${linesrgx[$i]} ]]; then
       echo "$i. line baaaad"
     fi
done 3<"$file"
```

I would maybe use `sed`, but that's probably only because I like the tool:

```
sed -n '
   1{/^#Version:/!=};
   2{/^#OS:/!=};
   3{/^#Author:/!=};
' "$file" | sed 's/.*/&. line baaad/'
```

The `=` prints current line. But using `awk` is just plain fun:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  rgx[1]="^#Version:";
  rgx[2]="^#OS :"
}
$0 !~ rgx[NR]{ print NR ". line bad" }
' "$file"
```

Note: Prefer lower case variables. Upper case variables are by convention meant to be exported to environment, like `COLUMNS`, `LINES`, `PWD`, `UID`, `IFS`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe?

```sh
case $(head -n 4 test.yml) in
    '#Version : 1.2
#OS : ubuntu
#Author : JJ
#ect : ect') ;;
    *) echo "$0: Not exactly the same" >&2;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using bash directly, it is handier to validate this with awk. For a single file you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ a[1]="#Version:"
            a[2]="#OS:"
            a[3]="#Author:"
     }
     !(FNR in a) { nextfile }
     !($0 ~ "^"a[FNR]) { print "mismatch header",FILENAME":"FNR }
    ' file1 file2 file3 ... filen
```

At the start of the execution, we define an array which contains the header. The index of the array is the line number, the value is the expected string. The first test we perform is to check if the line number `FNR` is an index of the array `a`. If it is not, move to the next file. The second test checks if the line matches the expected expression. If it does not, print  a warning message.

The output might look like:

```
mismatch header foo.yml:1
mismatch header foo.yml:3
mismatch header bar.yml:2
mismatch header qux.yml:1
mismatch header quux.yml:1
mismatch header quux.yml:2
mismatch header quux.yml:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ansible. For example, check 2 files

```sh
shell> cat test1.yml
#Version : 1.2
#OS : ubuntu
#Author : JJ
#ect : etc

shell> cat test2.yml
#Version : 1.3
#OS : ubuntu
#Author : JJ
#ect : etc
```

The playbook below reads the first 4 lines from the files and creates a dictionary with the differences

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: "head -n 4 {{ item }}"
      register: result
      loop:
        - test1.yml
        - test2.yml
    - set_fact:
        diffs: "{{ diffs|default({})|
                   combine({item.item: item.stdout_lines|difference(header)}) }}"
      loop: "{{ result.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      vars:
        header:
          - '#Version : 1.2'
          - '#OS : ubuntu'
          - '#Author : JJ'
          - '#ect : ect'
    - debug:
        var: diffs
```

gives

```
  diffs:
    test1.yml: []
    test2.yml:
    - '#Version : 1.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are looking for the string `#Version:` in the first four lines, you can use
Good old `awk`

```
awk 'NR>4 {exit} /^#Version/ {print NR ". line bad"}' "${FILE}"
```

This is much cleaner than working with pipes:

```
head -4 "${FILE}" | grep -n '^#Version' | sed -r 's/(.).*/\1. line bad/'
```

And only for when you want to learn more about `sed` you may look at (but don't  use):

```
sed -rn '/^#Version.*/=' "${FILE}" | sed -nr 's/^([1-4])$/\1. line bad/p'
```